# Meteor with React and Materialize initialization without jQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, material-design, materialize

So, what module do I need to include in my file to be able to initialize materialize scripts like this:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.dropdown-trigger');
var instance = M.Dropdown.init(elem, options);
```

I'm using materialize with meteor and React and I've installed materialize through Atmosphere. Thanks

Comment: Ever get this working?